# Having trouble merging cell data from a file. Characters are missing, so the final size is wrong, why?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm reading data from a file, merging 2nd and 3rd cells in each row, storing them in a new cell, then printing the data. Everything works fine except for two issues:

1. The first `'1'` in the first cell in the first row gets truncated. Why does that happen?
2. The value of `size` should have been 5, but it's 6. Why?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 20
    
int main()
{
    string arr[max][5], temp;
    int i=0, j, k;
    char ch;
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            if(j != 4)
                cin>>arr[i][j];
            else    
                arr[i][4] = arr[i][1]+arr[i][2];
        }
        i = i+1;

        //cout<<"\n";   
    }
    int size = i;
    cout<<"size: "<<size<<endl;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][0]<<" "<<arr[i][1]<<" "<<arr[i][2]<<" "<<arr[i][3];
        cout<<"\n"; 
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
15101049 PRIYESH DAMOR p.damor
15101061 SIMRAN SONI simran.soni
15101012 KAUTAV BASUMATARY b.kaustav
15101053 RAHUL KUMAR rahul053
15101028 DUDDU VARA vara
```

Output:

```
size: 6 //size should have been 5
5101049 PRIYESH DAMOR p.damor //'1' before '5' is missing
15101061 SIMRAN SONI simran.soni
15101012 KAUTAV BASUMATARY b.kaustav
15101053 RAHUL KUMAR rahul053
15101028 DUDDU VARA vara
```

Comment: `while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` is going to eat the first character of the file.

Comment: Side note stop using "C" style arrays, use `std::vector<std::vector<string>>` or since you always seem to read 4 strings per line use `std::vector<std::array<std::string,4>>`

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for: it runs your program, one line at a time, and [shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)!! This is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: It'd be interesting to hear what you _think_ will happen to the character read in `while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: Why are you using `freopen`?  I have never used it in over 40 years of C and C++ programming.  The programs that need to open a file, use `std::ifstream::open` or use the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Because the first `1` is consumed by `getchar()` and you are not using `ch`.

**2.** Because the `EOF` check passes seeing the newline character at the end of 5th line and it proceeds to try to read the 6th line.

Instead of the `while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` loop, try this:

```cpp
    while(cin>>temp) // try to read first element, stop if it fails
    {
        arr[i][0] = temp; // assign what is read
        for(j=1; j<5; j++) // read the rest elements
        {
            if(j != 4)
                cin>>arr[i][j];
            else
                arr[i][4] = arr[i][1]+arr[i][2];
        }
        i = i+1;
        
        //cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A more idiomatic way of reading the file in C++ is to use a stream, to and to use std::vector if you don't know the size of your array at compile time (instead  of pre-allocating 20 lines and hoping that will be enough)

Also explicitly checking for EOF is usually not needed either, which will prevent your code from eating characters unecessarily too.

You then end up with something like this (online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/AjFQ8mL8l)

```
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

static std::istringstream testfile
{
"15101049 PRIYESH DAMOR p.damor\n"
"15101061 SIMRAN SONI simran.soni\n"
"15101012 KAUTAV BASUMATARY b.kaustav\n"
"15101053 RAHUL KUMAR rahul053\n"
"15101028 DUDDU VARA vara\n"
};


auto load(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string,4>> lines;
    std::array<std::string,4> line;
    // read a line, if it cant read a full line it will return false
    while(is>>line[0]>>line[1]>>line[2]>>line[3])
    {
        // add this line to the collection of lines
        // this is why using std::vector is so convenient
        // it will allocate extra memory when needed
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    return lines;
}


int main()
{
    auto lines = load(testfile); // easily replaced by a std::ifstream

    std::cout << "number of lines = " << lines.size() << "\n";
    for(const auto& line : lines)
    {
        std::cout << line[0] << " " << line[1] << " " << line[2] << " " << line[3] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note in a full solution I would not read to std::array, but to a struct of my own making. But I don't know what your entries mean so I can't make a struct with meaningful names.